# c# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'UnityEngine.CursorLockMode'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to make a menu system in unity using c#

the script I use to hide and show keeps coming back with this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'UnityEngine.CursorLockMode'

here is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Canvas;
    public GameObject Camera;
    bool Paused = false;

    void Start(){
        Canvas.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) {
            if(Paused == true){
                Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
                Canvas.gameObject.SetActive (false);
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Cursor.lockState = true;
                Paused = false;
            } else {
                Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
                Canvas.gameObject.SetActive (true);
                Cursor.visible = true;
                Cursor.lockState = false;
                Paused = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Resume(){
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
        Canvas.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Cursor.lockState is not a boolean property but it is a CursorLockMode enum property. See the possible values http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html

Answer (score 3):

[`Cursor.lockState`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html) isn't a boolean, is of type [`CursorLockMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html).

You need to set it to `CursorLockMode.Locked` or possibly `CursorLockMode.Confined` (depending on what you want to do) and `CursorLockMode.None`